# Python : Getting "OverflowError: repeated string is too long" when creating dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, micropython

I'm trying to convert this line of code :

`array_of_power1.append(dict(measurement=topic_mqtt_power1,timestamp=int(epoch_time_stamp * 1000000000),fields=dict(power=power1),tags=dict(MachineType=Machine_type,MachineName=Machine_name)))`

into

```
array_of_power1.append({'measurement' : 'topic_mqtt_power1', 'timestamp' : 'epoch_time_stamp' * 1000000000, fields: {'power' : 'power1'}, tags: {MachineType : Machinetype, MachineName : Machine_name}})
```

and I'm getting

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    OverflowError: repeated string is too long

The reason why I'm changing from the dict struct to the other method is that the dict struct  "dict()" doesnt work in micropython.

Comment: by writing `'epoch_time_stamp' * 1000000000 ` you are writing _epoch_time_stamp_ **1000000000** time, remove the `*`

Comment: makes sense now, thanks!   the second problem i have is its showing "NameError: name 'fields' is not defined"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run something like this to avoid the error of  *OverflowError* and *NameError* :

```
array_of_power1.append({'measurement' : 'topic_mqtt_power1', 
                        'timestamp' : 'epoch_time_stamp x 1000000000',
                        'fields': {'power' : 'power1'}, 
                        'tags': {MachineType : Machinetype, MachineName : Machine_name}})
```